# Problems with res.redirect in Node.js (Express)

Tags: node.js, express

I have a button that does a POST request via AJAX, and I want to refresh the page when it finishes.

So, my AJAX does a POST to `/upgrade`:

`app.post("/upgrade", game.upgrade);`

```
exports.upgrade = function(req,res){
    player.findOne({name:req.session.name}, function(err, doc){
        //doing something
        doc.save(function(err){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            else res.redirect("/game/buildings");
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see, the `redirect` goes to `/game/buildings`

`app.get('/game/buildings', game.buildings);`

```
export.buildings = function(req,res){
    playerDB.findOne({name:req.session.name}, function(err, doc){
        //doing something
        res.render('./game/buildings', {username:req.session.name});
    }
}
```

The problem is that `res.redirect` in the upgrade method works, but in the `buldings` handler, the `res.render` seems to be ignored.

I added a `console.log("session: "+req.session.name)` inside the `buildings` method, and it's ok. All data seems to be ok, but the `res.render` doesn't work.

In the console log, when I go to the `/game/buildings` path using the menu (this way works fine), it prints something like this:

```
routing to buildings
session: Neoares
[90mGET /game/buildings [32m200 [90m48ms - 6.58kb[0m
[90mGET /javascripts/jquery.js [36m304 [90m0ms[0m
[90mGET /javascripts/game.js [36m304 [90m1ms[0m
[90mGET /stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css [36m304 [90m1ms[0m
[90mGET /stylesheets/justified-nav.css [36m304 [90m1ms[0m
[90mGET /images/buildings/wishing_well.svg [36m304 [90m1ms[0m
[90mGET /images/resources/wood.png [36m304 [90m1ms[0m
[90mGET /images/resources/stone.png [36m304 [90m2ms[0m
[90mGET /images/resources/iron.png [36m304 [90m1ms[0m
```

But when I go via the AJAX button, It only prints this:

```
routing to buildings
session: Neoares
[90mGET /game/buildings [32m200 [90m98ms - 6.58kb[0m
```

Comment: Are your views settings set for your Express app? If so, what are they set to?

Comment: I think you mean this: `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`. Is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AJAX and redirects are not compatible. AJAX by definition is interacting with the server in a separate context from which URL the browser has loaded in the address bar. So doing an AJAX request and then responding with a redirect does not automatically affect the browser's `window.location` at all, and therefore it is almost always a mistake to send a redirect to an AJAX request. What you can do is just use javascript in the browser to set `window.location` to the correct path if your POST to `/upgrade` succeeds.